# Flutter - How the plugin have the security and trust warranted?

Tags: flutter

If you are developing some app for a company, this means that your app might have some high level of complexity and functionalities (caching, geolocation, network). So probably, we will end up needing to use some plugins from the pub.dev

My Question is: How the plugin have the security and trust warranted?

It is near impossible to debug each plugin's line of code, trying to find some security flaws or data stealing.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Could you clarify your question or maybe rephrase it? Are you asking how we can trust plugins? or how to verify their security?

Comment: Mate, most of them are open source so you can just check that. And there are plugins that are verified by flutter if you're really stringent about it